# saving form attributes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I wrote .net code and  want anyone to help me and tell if this is right or not :). I made a form with two checkboxes and two picture boxes and a button and want to save values of the checkbox and the picture box when I close the form and reload these values again after rerun.

The code I wrote:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.UserBackColor;

        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\red.jpg");
            Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: i did and i didn't get the required result so i need the right answer

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Upgrade()` is incorrect here. It is used to update settings after an application upgrade.

Remove that line and everything should work fine and dandy.

There's a nice short article on CodeProject that explains the use of application settings: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C